# What's a portable value for UINT_MIN?

Tags: c++, c, unsigned-integer

In `limits.h`, there are #defines for `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` (and SHRT_* and LONG_* and so on), but only `UINT_MAX`.

Should I define `UINT_MIN` myself? Is `0` (positive zero) a portable value?

Comment: +1 for caring enough about portability and correctness to ask.

Comment: I should give a -1 for senselessly wanting to remove the "magic number" 0. But oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be "typesafe" you could use `0U`, so if you use it in an expression you will have the correct promotions to `unsigned`.

Comment: So I should `#define UINT_MIN +0U` in `limits.h`?

Comment: Thinking of it, it is perhaps not so a good idea to have a file that has the same name as a standard file or to mess around with the later. I'd put it another place. If you want to have a `+` to the `0U` (why?) you should have the whole in parenthesis `(+0U)` since otherwise you might have unwanted effects when the `+` could be interpreted as addition.

Comment: You don't need parenthesis. Even in `1+UINT_MIN`, it would expand to `1+ +0U`, which is a correct expression. Macro expansion happens at token level, and will not glue the two plusses together.

Comment: @MSalters: I think you need it since it makes invalid sequences valid. Something like `5 UINT_MIN` would become valid, where it really shouldn't.

Comment: @Jens: Using that logic, I can equally say that you must _not_ have parenthesis as it makes invalid sequences valid. Something like `sin UINT_MIN` becomes valid.

Comment: @MSalters: good point. So it is a matter of taste which invalid sequences should become valid ;-) Brings us back to the question, why using the `+` in the first place? `0U` would be much simpler, then, and is really a well defined constant.

Comment: ++ for the pedantic type safety note; you tickled my humour :)

Answer (score 20):

It's an unsigned integer - by definition its smallest possible value is 0.  If you want some justification besides just common sense, the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) says:

> **6.2.6.2 Integer types**
>
> 1. For unsigned integer types other than `unsigned char`, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need not be any of the latter). If there are *N* value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2 between 1 and 2^(*N*−1), so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from 0 to 2^(*N*−1) using a pure binary representation; this shall be known as the value representation. The values of any padding bits are unspecified.

Comment: love the standard. especially when it's quoted.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: @Ariel, how does it not answer your question?  The minimum value for an unsigned type is defined by the standard to be 0.

Comment: the last  `2^(N-1)`  should be `(2^N)-1` instead e.g., for `N=8` `UCHAR_MAX = (2^8)-1 = 255`

Answer (score 7):

You could use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min()`.

Comment: This will work in C++, and this will not work in C. What is C/C++?

Comment: Our source tree contains C and C++ and so this need to work with both. This is why I tagged the question with both.